# How to redirect output of here document to a text file?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, kerberos

I am trying to fetch list of kerberos principals using heredocument.

How can i redirect the output of the heredocument to a text file.
Below script work without redirection to text file.

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh root@remotehost  <<-EOF 
kadmin.local
list_principals *host1*
EOF

output:
HTTP/host1.karthik.com@KARTHIK.COM
hadoop/host1.karthik.com@KARTHIK.COM
host/host1.karthik.com@KARTHIK.COM
```

But if i try to redirect the out put to text file i will get error.

Things which din't worked :

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh root@remotehost  <<-EOF > test.txt
kadmin.local
list_principals *host1*
EOF

output:
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

#!/bin/bash
ssh root@remotehost  cat <<-EOF > test.txt
kadmin.local
list_principals *host1*
EOF

output:
kadmin.local
list_principals *host1*
```

Comment: May be use `-T` in `ssh` for `-T, Disable pseudo-terminal allocation.`

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh root@remotehost  > test.txt <<-EOF 
kadmin.local
list_principals *host1*
EOF
```

---

**Test:**

```
$ sh > out.dat <<- EOF
date
EOF

$ cat out.dat
Mon Mar 20 09:49:18 EDT 2017
```